# Alter the text in the p tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to alter the text in the p tags to gain (upon clicking the text) the properties set by the attribution class.

Here is the HTML:

```
<p onclick="function">Hello</p>
```

CSS:

```
.attribution{
color:blue;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var main = function() {
$('<p>').text('.attribution');
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <p onclick="function">Hello</p>
> ```

You:

1. Have to use the name of the function, not the keyword `function` which creates a new function.
2. Have to actually call the function, by appending `()` to the variable name
3. Shouldn't use intrinsic event attributes at all. Bind event handlers with JavaScript.

So

```
<p>Hello</p>

<script>
    $("p").on("click", main);
</script>
```

> ```
> var main = function() {
> $('<p>').text('.attribution');
> };
> $(document).ready(main);
> ```

You:

1. Should use a function declaration (since it plays nicely with debuggers)
2. Need to select the existing paragraph instead of creating (and promptly discarding) a new one)
3. Add `attribution` to the classes on the element instead of replacing the text content of it with the phrase `".attribution"`
4. Not call the function on DOM ready when you want it to be called when something is clicked

Such

```
function main() {
   $('p').addClass('attribution');
};
```

---

As an aside, paragraphs are not designed to be interactive. While you *can* click on them with a mouse pointer, nothing encourages people to do so, they are outside the normal focus list (so people who don't use a mouse can't tab to them) and don't show up in screen readers as something that should be clicked on. Use appropriate markup (perhaps a button).

Comment: “intrinsic”? Aren’t they called “inline”?

Comment: @Xufox — "inline" is any script that isn't linked from an external resource.

Comment: @Quentin hey, i tried that but it didn't work. might this be because I'm using a text editor [brackets] that might cause the javascript to not be applied?

Comment: @tombros — No. Text is text.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since your loading JQuery why no use its methods for handling click events and changing the css properties.

```js
$( "p" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).addClass('attribution');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You are not actually hooking any callback function to onclick event. You need to specifiy what function you want to be executed on click.
So:
HTML:

```
<p onclick="addClass(event)">Hello</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addClass(evt){
        evt.target.classList.add('attribution');
    }
```

jQuery alternative:

```
var main = function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("attribution");
    });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    main();
});
```